# Error when use Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: json, json.net

I´m trying to use Newtonsoft to deserialize a Json string, but I´m getting this error :

An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ShopFacilBradescoTeste.Erros' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Path 'erros.$values', line 1, position 45.

This is my Json Data :

string json = @"{""$id"": ""1"",""erros"": {""$id"": ""2"",""$values"": []},""isValid"": true,""message"": null,""retornoConsulta"": {""$id"": ""3"",""$values"": [{""$id"": ""4"",""tipoLogradouro"": ""Rua"",""logradouro"": ""Abel Tavares"",""bairro"": ""Jardim Belém"",""localidade"": ""São Paulo"",""uf"": ""SP"",""cep"": ""03810110""}]}}";

Retorno result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

And these are my classes :

```
public class Retorno
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Erros erros { get; set; }
    public bool isValid { get; set; }
    public object message { get; set; }
    public Retornoconsulta retornoConsulta { get; set; }
}

public class Erros
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public object[] values { get; set; }
}

public class Retornoconsulta
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Values[] values { get; set; }
}

public class Values
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string tipoLogradouro { get; set; }
    public string logradouro { get; set; }
    public string bairro { get; set; }
    public string localidade { get; set; }
    public string uf { get; set; }
    public string cep { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON doesn't look like a JSON. But that's ok, there are helper classes that can massage those kinks out.

This should do it:

```
parsedJson = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(json);
Retorno result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(parsedJson);
```

I just tested it on my IDE, seem to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like this

```
string json = @"[ {""$id"": ""1"",""erros"": {""$id"": ""2"",""$values"": []},""isValid"": true,""message"": null,""retornoConsulta"": {""$id"": ""3"",""$values"": [{""$id"": ""4"",""tipoLogradouro"": ""Rua"",""logradouro"": ""Abel Tavares"",""bairro"": ""Jardim Belém"",""localidade"": ""São Paulo"",""uf"": ""SP"",""cep"": ""03810110""}]} ] }";
```

You need to have like this

Your data must be between [ and ] for JSON array